Should I have used the number-sequence tag for my question?
Recently I posted the following question:
Must there exist, somewhere in the sequence an odd number immediately followed by an even number?
Considering that my question is not a typical What is the next number in the sequence? puzzle, should I have used the number-sequence tag?

No - the tag description for number-sequence says:

A puzzle in which the hidden pattern behind a given sequence of numbers (and, often, the next term) is to be found.

The emphasis here is on determining a hidden pattern. However, the question to which you refer does not pertain to a pattern, hidden or otherwise. Rather, it focuses on mathematical argument and proof, and it just happens that the subject is a sequence of numbers.
If I was searching for a 'number sequence' puzzle, I wouldn't expect to see a question like yours among them. I think your use of the mathematics tag alone is correct.
